# Адаптивный nav bar из четырех кнопок шириной 25% и анимацией при скролле

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день.

**Дано:**

nav bar (width 100%, height 200px), состоящий из четырех горизонтальных кнопок кнопок (width 25%, height 200px), которые уменьшаются при скролле.

**Задача:**

при уменьшении ширины экрана до 499px и ниже, nav bar из 4 кнопок превращается в вертикальное меню, которое открывается по клику на "Menu" (width 100%, height 40px). Анимация при скроле не важна.

**Cложности:**

безуспешно плаваю в позиционировании и родительстве, правки связанных (по моему мнению) атрибутов приводят к проблемам (экран <500px). При нажатии кнопки Menu:

- кнопки (Home, blog, ...) располагаются горизонтально
- кнопки (Home, blog, ...) располагаются вертикально, но видимая только одна кнопка
- слово 'Menu' выходи за рамки
- элемент становится активным при наведении области за кнопкой
- при скроле появляются линии, смещается активная область, слетает позиция слова "Menu" и т.д.

На данном этапе слово "Menu" внутри кнопки на нужном месте, при клике открывается вертикальное меню с видимым только одной кнопкой. При скроле кнопка пропадает вовсе (это связано со скриптом, после решения этой задачи отредактирую скрипт или отключу анимацию).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header" id="nav">
  <a href="#" class="menu-trigger">MENU</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="main_button" href="#">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a class="blog_button" href="#">BLOG</a></li>
     <li><a class="contact_button" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
     <li><a class="about_button" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* BODY */

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 200px;
}

/* HEADER */

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    color:black;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:160px;
}

.header li {
    width: 25%; text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 100;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9ced8;
}

/* HIGHLIGHT HEADING */

a:hover{
    background-color: #cdddf7;
    color: #0B3C5D;
}


/* NAVGIATION BUTTONS */

.main_button {
    border-right: 1px solid #c9ced8;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.main_button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 183, 160, 0.5);
}

.blog_button {
    border-right: 1px solid #c9ced8;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.blog_button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(152, 113, 242, 0.5);
}

.contact_button {
    border-right: 1px solid #c9ced8;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.contact_button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(34, 126, 163, 0.4);
}

.about_button {
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.about_button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(162, 214, 107, 0.4);
}

/* NAV BAR BECOMES SMALL ON SCROLL */
.header.shrink {
    height: 100px;
    line-height:80px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9ced8; 
}


/* PROBLEM AREA - MOBILE VERSION */

.menu-trigger {
  display:none;
  height: 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #d5dce8;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .menu-trigger {
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px #79896D solid;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  a:hover{
    background-color: #d5dce8;
    color: black;
  }
  .header ul li { 
    color: #d5dce8;
    font-size: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .header ul {
    display:none;
    height: 30px;    
  }
  .header li {
    width: 100%; text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .header {
    line-height: 45px;
  }
  .header.shrink {
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 74px;
  }
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
           $('.header').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
        }
  });
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.header ul').slideToggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle

  $(window).resize(function() {
        if (  $(window).width() > 500 ) {
            $('.header ul').removeAttr('style');
         }
    });//end resize
});//end ready
```

[Полный код nav bar'a copepen](https://codepen.io/krvstk/pen/BdMdqG)

[Пример, по которому работаю](https://codepen.io/docode/pen/QbbQwm)

Переписывая, весь nav bar с нуля сталкивался с другими сложностями и возвращался к месту, где корректно отображался nav bar и анимация к нему. Отдаю себе отчет что код, мягко говоря, перегружен и он крайне далек от идеала, но буду признателен если получу любые подсказки или советы. Спасибо что дочитали до этого места.

Comment: Интересует фикс текущего кода или можно и альтернативу?

Comment: Для меня главное (1) Что-бы меню состояло из четырех одинаковых кнопок по 200px плотно прилипающих друг к другу (2) При скроле уменьшался их размер (3) На экранах <500px нав бар превращался в вертикальное меню. Каким методом этого достичь - неважно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так. Размер шрифта для кнопок специально был задан 20px, что бы на 501px ширины они влезали. В остальном вроде все работает как надо.

Вообще, данный подход имеет очень существенную проблему - если элементов меню много, то они не влезут в экран.

На всякий случай сохранил [Pen](https://codepen.io/MedvedevDev/pen/Gvzddx)

```js
$(function() {
  menu();
})

function menu() {
  const $window = $(window),
    $menu = $('.menu'),
    $button = $menu.find('.menu_button'),
    $menuContent = $menu.find('.menu_content');

  $window.on('scroll', onScroll);
  $button.on('click', toggleMenu);

  function onScroll() {
    $menu.toggleClass('shrink', $window.scrollTop() > 0);
  }

  function toggleMenu() {
    $menuContent.toggleClass('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.page { height: 300vh; }

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu_button {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #d5dce8;
}

.menu_content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .4s linear;
}

.menu_list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0 solid #c9ced8;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  transition: height .4s ease, background-color .2s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu_item:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.menu_item:last-child { border-right: 0; }

.menu_item-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.menu_link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu.shrink .menu_item {
  height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .menu_button { display: block; }
  .menu_content { max-height: 0; }
  .menu_content.show { max-height: 100vh; }
  
  .menu_item {
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <nav class="menu">
    <button class="menu_button" type="button">Menu</button>
    <div class="menu_content">
      <ul class="menu_list">
        <li class="menu_item"><span class="menu_item-name">Home</span><a class="menu_link" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><span class="menu_item-name">About</span><a class="menu_link" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><span class="menu_item-name">Contact</span><a class="menu_link" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><span class="menu_item-name">Products</span><a class="menu_link" href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Данный код прекрасно решил мою проблему! Подточил под остальной код и залил на сервер. Все прекрасно работает. Буду учить его что-бы понять КАК оно работает и зачем столько разных классов.